# Add summarizing column with calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, summarization

I need to show serial numbers for each row of an invoice. That means, that on one position there can be several serial numbers. Along with the serial number there needs to be a quantity, which is obviously allways one. Unfortunately, there could be rows with more items than serial numbers. This happens when serial numbers are not scanned in the shipping process. In my output I need an extra row for these positions where I show the number of REMAINING items. So let's say, that there is a position with 10 items in it and only four are scanned in the shipping process. That would mean I print four rows with the serials and quantity one and a fith row with no serial and the quantity six.

I work with SQL Server 2008 and would prefer a solution without temp tables or CTEs.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
CREATE TABLE #data (doc int, pos int, qty int)
CREATE TABLE #serial (doc int, pos int, serial varchar(10))

INSERT INTO #data
SELECT 1,1,6
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,2,3
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,1,4

INSERT INTO #serial
select 1,1,'aaaaaaaaaa'
UNION ALL
select 1,1,'bbbbbbbbbb'
UNION ALL
select 1,1,'cccccccccc'
UNION ALL
select 1,1,'dddddddddd'
UNION ALL
select 1,2,'eeeeeeeeee'
UNION ALL
select 1,2,'ffffffffff'
UNION ALL
select 1,2,'gggggggggg'
UNION ALL
select 2,1,'hhhhhhhhhh'

SELECT d.doc, d.pos, s.serial, CASE WHEN s.serial IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE d.qty END qty
FROM #data d
INNER JOIN #serial s ON s.doc = d.doc and s.pos = d.pos
```

This is the desired output:

```
doc | pos | serial     | qty
1   | 1   |'aaaaaaaaaa'| 1
1   | 1   |'bbbbbbbbbb'| 1
1   | 1   |'cccccccccc'| 1
1   | 1   |'dddddddddd'| 1
1   | 1   | NULL       | 2
1   | 2   |'eeeeeeeeee'| 1
1   | 2   |'ffffffffff'| 1
1   | 2   |'gggggggggg'| 1
2   | 1   |'hhhhhhhhhh'| 1
2   | 1   | NULL       | 3
```

Comment: Could you please explain your output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
  s.doc, s.pos, s.serial, d.qty - s.cnt qty
from
  (  select
    s.doc, s.pos, s.serial, count(*) cnt,
    case when grouping(s.doc) = 0 and grouping(s.pos) = 0 and grouping(s.serial) = 1 then 1 else 0 end grp
  from
    #serial s
  group by
    s.doc, s.pos, s.serial with cube
  having
    grouping(s.doc) = 0 and grouping(s.pos) = 0 and grouping(s.serial) = 1
    or grouping(s.doc) = 0 and grouping(s.pos) = 0 and grouping(s.serial) = 0
    ) s
  left join #data d on s.doc = d.doc and s.pos = d.pos and s.grp = 1
where
  s.grp = 0 or d.qty - s.cnt > 0
order by
  s.doc, s.pos, s.grp
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was searching for!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this ..?

```
SELECT d.doc, d.pos, s.serial, CASE WHEN s.serial IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE d.qty END qty
FROM @data d
INNER JOIN @serial s ON s.doc = d.doc AND s.pos = d.pos

UNION ALL

SELECT d.doc, d.pos, NULL serial, d.qty - s.qty
FROM @data d
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT doc, pos, count(*) AS qty
    FROM @serial
    GROUP BY doc, pos
    ) s ON s.doc = d.doc AND s.pos = d.pos
WHERE d.qty - s.qty <> 0
ORDER BY doc, pos
```

**Output**

```
doc pos serial  qty
1   1   aaaaaaaaaa  1
1   1   bbbbbbbbbb  1
1   1   cccccccccc  1
1   1   dddddddddd  1
1   1   NULL    2
1   2   eeeeeeeeee  1
1   2   ffffffffff  1
1   2   gggggggggg  1
2   1   hhhhhhhhhh  1
2   1   NULL    3
```

Comment: I'm searching for an approach, where I can avoid multiple joins of the same tables. Perhaps in the direction of ROLLUP or similar

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic approach

```
 SELECT d.doc, d.pos, s.serial, 1 qty
    FROM #data d
    INNER JOIN #serial s ON s.doc = d.doc and s.pos = d.pos
    UNION
    select t1.doc,t1.pos,null,t1.qty-ss from
    (
        SELECT d.doc,d.pos, SUM(1) SS , d.qty
        FROM #data d
        INNER JOIN #serial s ON s.doc = d.doc and s.pos = d.pos
        group by d.doc,d.pos,d.qty
    )t1 where SS<>qty
    Order by d.doc,d.pos,s.serial
```

Comment: I'm searching for an approach, where I can avoid multiple joins of the same tables. Perhaps in the direction of ROLLUP or similar